# How to remove the extra horizontal scrollbar adding automatically when modal is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap 3.0.0 modal.When i open it it adds an extra scrollbar at the background page inside the original scrollbar. I want to remove that extra scrollbar showing at pop up of modal. here is image of the my page when i open the scrollbar:

[image]

So please ,can anyone tell me how could i remove this extra scrollbar. . 
Thank you in advance  . ..

Comment: Providing live example (on jsfiddle, for example) would help immensely. Generally, setting overflow:hidden on container with extra scrollbar might help with your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this ,I made the changes in modal css and it worked fine for me . .

```
.modal{ overflow-y:hidden;}
```

and it removed an extra scrollbar . .

Answer (score 2):

you can do via css and jquery.

add your class for hide scrollbar.

```
 .modalClass {overflow-y: hidden;}
```

As if you want to add this via jquery put below line once your model is opened.

```
$('.modalclass').css({'overflow-y':'hidden'});
```

Hope this will help you.

Cheers!